# HTML - Background-color not changing for navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

Apologies for the rather stupid question. I am quite new to creating HTML web pages and I am just working on a basic homepage. I can't get the navbar `background-color` to change to any color but the `:hover` and the `.active` appear to work. I have been stuck on this for a couple of days looking it up on internet and moving code around to see whether it makes a difference...

Please excuse all the mistakes I probably would have made and thanks in advance!

I just get a bit demotivated when I hit a wall that seems rather simple.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <style>
    
    .header {
     background-color: white;
     padding: 15px;
     position: sticky;
     top: 0;
    }
    
    <!-- Menu CSS -->
    
    
    .topnav {
     overflow: hidden;
      /*THIS BIT IS NOT WORKING, THANKS*/
     background-color: red;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
     color: red;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
     overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: Yellow;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: red;
      color: blue;
    }
    
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  
    <div class="header">
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <a href="#news">News and Events</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#data">Data Protection</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please **Edit your code** to only show header and navigation with only their CSS. It would make us a lot easier. Also, you can use live code tool to make a live snippet!

Comment: The order of your CSS rules is important. The next one overwrites the previous, So keep that in mind. Actually, CSS stands for `cascading style sheets`. Cascading in the terms of the styles are being read from top to bottom. There's always the `!important ` additional property you can add. I suggest testing out the different classes and theirs properties inside of the Dev Tools to see if you can figure out what's really going on. -It always gets the job done for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to occur because you are using comment for HTML `<!-- Menu CSS -->` in CSS part of the page `<style>`. Same problem is in beginning of your style.

You should use CSS comments in `<style>` sections:

```
/* This is a CSS comment */
```

When you type a HTML comment instead of CSS one, it will **break whole style only for the following selector**. Rest of the code won't be affected.

---

Also, when I remove that comment, navigation bar is still not looking as it should.
This is because your navigation links `<a>` are set to `display: inline` as it is their default. You must change this to `display: inline-block` so it will still be in line but will take some space (square)

```css
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;

  /* You should use inline-block to make navigation links take some   space */
  display: inline-block;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: Yellow;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#services">Services</a>
      <a href="#news">News and Events</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#data">Data Protection</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

---

Please refer to these references

[Inline-block](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)
[CSS comments](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_comments.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the help on this! How come the comment only broke the background color and not any other sections of the CSS following it?

Comment: @Ribeye It actually broke whole `.topnav`. Folowing code doesn't get affected, only first after comment. If my answer did help you, consider [marking is as correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

IN general your code works, only problem: you are using red as a background-color for the `.topnav` AND as a text-color (`color`)  for the links in it (`.topnav a`). So change the link color to something else (white in my snippet)  to avoid red on red = invisible text for the links.

```css
.header {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 14px 0;
}

.topnav a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 16px;

}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: Yellow;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

    <!--<div class="imgstyle"><img src="C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\Website Work\google Logo\FTLOGO_Big.png" class="imgstyle"/></div>-->
    <a href="www.google.com"> <img style="float: Left;" alt="google" src="C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\Website Work\FTLOGO_Big.png" width="70%" height="60%"> </a>

    <a href="www.google.com"> <img style="float: right; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom:25px;" alt="Logo" src="C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\Website Work\Vector Logo.png" width="6%" height="6%"> </a>

    <img style="display: inline; padding-bottom:10px" src="C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\Website Work\google Logo\Tagline.png" width="70%" height="70%"/>

<div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#services">Services</a>
    <a href="#news">News and Events</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#data">Data Protection</a>
</div>

</div>
```